# Tengo problemas con mi programa

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio que involucra tuplas, funciones y vectores pero cuando lo compilo y lo corro me da cualquier valor menos el correcto no se si es un problema de mala utilización de las funciones o algo tan simple como algo que esta de mas. Si alguien puede ver el problema o conoce una pagina que trate de funciones con tuplas lo agradecería, cualquier comentario ayuda.

Mi código:

```
#include <stdbool.h>


#define NUM_CUSTOMERS 3

#define Small_Surface 50
#define Medium_Surface 100
#define Large_Surface 150
#define Extra_Large_Surface 200
typedef enum {
    SMALL_SURFACE, MEDIUM_SURFACE, LARGE_SURFACE, EXTRA_LARGE_SURFACE} tBuiltSurfaceType;

typedef struct {
    char fullAddress;
    float surface;
    tBuiltSurfaceType surfaceType;
} tAddress;

typedef struct {
    int id;
    char fullName;
    tAddress address;
    bool isPolicyHolder;
    float insurancePremium;
} tCustomer;
typedef struct {
    tCustomer policyHoldersVector[NUM_CUSTOMERS];
    int numPolicyHolders;
} tPolicyHolders;

int cheapestInsurancePremium (tCustomer customersVector[]){
    int selectedCustomer;
    float segurocustomer1=0;
    float segurocustomer2=0;
    float segurocustomer3=0;
    

    if(customersVector[1].isPolicyHolder==true){
            segurocustomer1 = (customersVector[1].insurancePremium / customersVector[1].address.surface);
            
        }else{
            segurocustomer1=0;
        }
    
    if(customersVector[2].isPolicyHolder==true){
            segurocustomer2 = (customersVector[2].insurancePremium / customersVector[2].address.surface);
        
        }else{
            segurocustomer2=0;
        }
    
    if(customersVector[3].isPolicyHolder==true){
            segurocustomer3 = (customersVector[3].insurancePremium / customersVector[3].address.surface);
        }else{
            segurocustomer3=0;
        }
    
    
    if(segurocustomer1==0 || segurocustomer2==0 || segurocustomer3==0){
        if (segurocustomer1==0 && segurocustomer2==0){
                selectedCustomer = 3;
            }else{
                if (segurocustomer1==0 && segurocustomer3==0){
                        selectedCustomer = 2;
                    }else{
                        if (segurocustomer2==0 && segurocustomer3==0){
                            selectedCustomer = 1;
                        }
                    }
            }
if(segurocustomer1==0){
                if (segurocustomer2 <= segurocustomer3){
                        selectedCustomer=2;
                    }else{
                        selectedCustomer=3;
                    }
        }
                
        if(segurocustomer2==0){
                if (segurocustomer1 <= segurocustomer3){
                        selectedCustomer=1;
                    }else{
                        selectedCustomer=3;
                    }
        }
                
        if(segurocustomer3==0){
                if (segurocustomer1 <= segurocustomer2){
                        selectedCustomer=1;
                    }else{
                        selectedCustomer=2;                 
                    }
        }
        
    }else{
if  ((segurocustomer1 <= segurocustomer2) && (segurocustomer1 <= segurocustomer3)){
                    selectedCustomer = 1;
            }else {
                if ((segurocustomer2 <= segurocustomer1) && (segurocustomer2 <= segurocustomer3)) {
                        selectedCustomer = 2;
                    }else {
                        if ((segurocustomer3 <= segurocustomer1) && (segurocustomer3<= segurocustomer2)) {
                            selectedCustomer = 3;
                        }
                    }
            }
    }

    return selectedCustomer;
}   
    void readCustomer(tCustomer customersVector);
void writeCustomer(tCustomer customersVector);
    
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    tCustomer customersVector[NUM_CUSTOMERS];
    tPolicyHolders policyHolders;
    policyHolders.numPolicyHolders= 0; 
    int selectedCustomer= 0;
    
    for (int i=0;i<NUM_CUSTOMERS; i++) {
        printf("ENTER DATA CUSTOMER #%d\n",i+1);
        readCustomer(customersVector[i]);
        if (customersVector[i].isPolicyHolder==true){
         policyHolders.numPolicyHolders++;
    }
    }
if (policyHolders.numPolicyHolders > 0) {
            cheapestInsurancePremium(customersVector);
            printf("RESULT\n");
            writeCustomer(customersVector[selectedCustomer]); 
        }else{ 
                   
                printf("NO POLICY HOLDERS RECOVERED.\n");
        }
    return 0;
    }
void readCustomer(tCustomer customersVector){
    printf( "ID? (AN INTEGER) >>\n");   
    scanf("%d",&customersVector.id); 
    printf( "FULL NAME? (25 CHAR MAX, NO SPACES) >>\n");   
    scanf("%s",&customersVector.fullName);
    printf( "FULL ADDRESS? (35 CHAR MAX, NO SPACES) >>\n");    
    scanf("%s",&customersVector.address.fullAddress);
    printf( "SURFACE? (IN M2) >>\n");   
    scanf("%f",&customersVector.address.surface );    
        if (customersVector.address.surface <= Small_Surface){
            customersVector.address.surfaceType = SMALL_SURFACE;   
        } else {
            if (customersVector.address.surface <= Medium_Surface){       
                customersVector.address.surfaceType = MEDIUM_SURFACE;     
            }else{    
                if (customersVector.address.surface <= Large_Surface){         
                    customersVector.address.surfaceType = LARGE_SURFACE;       
                }else {        
                    customersVector.address.surfaceType = EXTRA_LARGE_SURFACE;
                }  
            }   
        }      
        
    printf( "IS POLICY HOLDER? (0-FALSE, 1-TRUE) >>\n");  
    scanf("%d",(int*)&customersVector.isPolicyHolder );
    
    printf( "INSURANCE PREMIUM [EUR]? (A REAL) >>\n");   
    scanf("%f",&customersVector.insurancePremium );
}
void writeCustomer(tCustomer customersVector){
    printf("ID: %d \n", customersVector.id);
    printf("FULL NAME: %d \n",customersVector.fullName);
    printf("SURFACE [M2]: %.2f \n",customersVector.address.surface);
    printf("SURFACE TYPE (1-SMALL, 2-MEDIUM, 3-LARGE, 4-EXTRA LARGE): %d \n", customersVector.address.surfaceType);
    printf("IS POLICY HOLDER (0-FALSE, 1-TRUE): %d \n", customersVector.isPolicyHolder);
    if (customersVector.isPolicyHolder == true) {
        printf("INSURANCE PREMIUM [EUR]: %.2f\n", customersVector.insurancePremium);
    }   
}
```

El programa cosiste en básicamente en a partir de tres clientes, obtener aquel que posee la póliza de seguros más económica por metro cuadrado de la vivienda utilizando funciones y tuplas.

Comment: Tu código tiene casi 180 líneas. ¿ No has podido acotar algo donde está el problema ? Te sugiero consultar lo que es un [mcve]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Tu programa no funciona porque no estás actualizando en ningún momento el vector `customersVector`. En efecto vemos que la función `readCustomer` recibe una copia de un objeto de tipo `tCustomer`:

```
void readCustomer(tCustomer customersVector);
```

Al ser una copia, todo cambio que se realice en dicho objeto dentro de la función se perderá al finalizar la misma.

Para poder modificar elementos externos a una función es necesario que la misma reciba un puntero al objeto. De paso también sería conveniente que la variable tuviese un nombre adecuado:

```
void readCustomer(tCustomer * customer);
```

Ten en cuenta que este cambio implica modificar tanto la llamada a `readCustomer` que haces en `main` como todos los usos de `customer` que se encuentran dentro de la propia función `readCustomer`.

Para próximas ocasiones, por favor, haz caso de los comentarios que te ha dejado @Trauma. He respondido simplemente porque he visto el error antes de pasar de largo a la siguiente pregunta.